# Possibly bricked PC after overclocking and frequency change

Tags: bios, power-supply, operating-systems, desktop-computer, overclocking

I helped my friend configure some settings on his BIOS from his custom build PC he made not too long ago, what we did was change the frequency of the RAM, which wasn't too large, and was good as my friend said, and he also overclocked the CPU, which he also said was ok.

We were stuck at trying to save the settings we changed, and after pressing a couple of buttons, we exited the BIOS, and a black screen, after a while we forcefully shut it down, and rebooted it, then nothing happened as well, not a single thing outputting to the screen. I do remember when we were dealing with the RAM, we saw a setting called voltage or smth, so my assumption is since we didn't regulate the voltage in the RAM, could that have possibly bricked our computer? the weirdest thing is that nor the mouse or keyboard light up anymore.

Comment: You have to reset BIOS settings using a jumper. Refer to motherboard's manual. I can't provide more details because you haven't specified what motherboard you have.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it out in a bit.